# Calling a dynamically created event handler from an event handler method of dynamic button

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, visual-studio

I have created a dynamic button called btn. The handler of the btn makes a call to a function for generating a dynamic button called secondbtn. secondbtn is associated with an event handler which should print "Please work" on screen. When I run my program the first dynamic button called btn is created and  when I click on btn it fires the event handler for the btn which generates the secondbtn. When I click on secondbtn the secondbtn disappears. I have attached my code below

```
Function generateEntireForm(ByVal panelOne As Panel)
    Dim btn As New Button
    panelOne.ID = "tstpanelID"
    btn.ID = "test1"
    btn.Text = "First"
    AddHandler btn.Click, AddressOf Test
    panelOne.Controls.Add(btn)

End Function


Public Sub Test(sender As Object, e As EventArgs)

    Dim panelBox As Panel = DirectCast(sender.FindControl("tstpanelID"), Panel)
    generateTopPanelForSearchMode(panelBox)
End Sub



Function generateTopPanelForSearchMode(ByVal firstpanel As Panel)
    Dim secondbtn As New Button
    secondbtn.ID = "Second"
    secondbtn.Text = "Second"
    AddHandler secondbtn.Click, AddressOf TestTwo
    firstpanel.Controls.Add(secondbtn)

End Function

Public Sub TestTwo(sender As Object, e As EventArgs)
    System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("Please work")

End Sub
```

Thank you for your help!

Comment: What are “Dim panelFromOne As Panel = sender” and “generateTopPanelForSearchMode(panelFromOne)” doing at the end of TestTwo?

Comment: They are just extra stuff that I was trying to mess with. The program doesnot even trigger the TestTwo event handler when I click the secondbtn. The program runs smoothly and ingnores the handler for secondbtn when I click on secondbtn.